# Chrome web app to fetch data from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, chrome-web-store

I have a simple web app which gets values from users and stores it in MYSQL. The app is written in PHP.

I'm in the process of developing a chrome web app for the same. The HTML part is done. However I'm not user on how I can fetch the data from the database and display it in the chrome app window.

The web app uses Angular JS, PHP, MySQL.

thanks in advance.

Edit:

HTML

```
<form>
        <div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <input type="text" x-webkit-speech class="form-control" ng-model="mytask" placeholder="enter your task" > 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button ng-click='AddTask();' class="btn btn-success">Add Task</button>
    </form>
```

JS

```
$scope.AddTask = function() {
//$scope.errors.splice(0, $scope.errors.length); // remove all error messages
//$scope.msgs.splice(0, $scope.msgs.length); 
$http.post('create_task.php', {'mytask': $scope.mytask, done:false}
    ).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log($scope.mytask);
        $scope.mytask = "";
```

This works fine in a web app, but not in a chrome web app. Any idea how I can make it work?

Comment: This is a very broad question.  Do you have a little bit of code that would give us a starting point?

Comment: this is stackoverflow ..we need codes ..;)